# Windows 7 => Windows 10 Upgrade, can't reset

Tags: windows-10, reset

This is a laptop that came with Windows 7 professional. Then when Windows 10 update became available, I upgraded it so for neither of the systems I have an installation media. I'm trying to reset it because it has become sluggish and generally would like to clean it up.

I go to Recovery => Reset This PC => Remove Everything It says it can't find the recovery environment and I need to insert the installation media.

Comment: So download them?  [Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/1046062#1046062) [Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench).  Just install Windows 10 over the current installation, from within Windows 10, when asked what to keep select "keep nothing" the end result is identical to the Reset feature within Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because normally when you install the OS it will create a small partition of basic settings that it needs in this case called the recovery partition.

If it's missing, and my old laptop had the same problem, you will likely need to get a disk from the Laptop manufacturer for about 20 bucks...depending because it will come with the vendor licensed version of windows -with all of the bloat-ware unfortunately.

If you want to continue to fiddle around you can try with another computer to get an installable media such as a disk or USB stick with by following the directions at Microsoft https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10 under the subheading "need to create a USB, DVD, or ISO." insert the media and try a repair. or insert the media just before you try to factory reset. You could also try to install the OS completely by booting from the media, but I cannot guarantee you will be able to verify a license this way since it was likely bought in bulk by whomever made your Laptop. On the plus side Windows 10 is supposed to be linked by account to hardware so that might work...I just haven't dealt with a laptop since they changed this model and expect them to refer you to the Laptop manufacturer for a recovery disk.